# How to get rid of conflicting server name warning for NginX?

Tags: nginx, server

I am getting this warning when I run `sudo nginx -t` to check the syntax of my NginX config file:

```
2024/03/13 11:01:15 [warn] 779261#779261: conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2024/03/13 11:01:15 [warn] 779261#779261: conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2024/03/13 11:01:15 [warn] 779261#779261: conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
2024/03/13 11:01:15 [warn] 779261#779261: conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
```

This is my NginX configuration:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    if ($host = 'example.com') {
      return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    root /var/www/example/code/public;

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/ruby;

}
```

How can I get rid of the warning?

Comment: Use `sudo nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and identify where the duplicate `server` blocks and `server_name` statements are being read from. Sometimes a text editor leaves backup files behind that can lead to duplication.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That command revealed indeed a duplicate file named `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.conf.save` which I did not know of. I deleted that file and now everything works!